# What is consuming too much memory in this script?

Tags: php, sql, memory

I'm having a problem here related to memory being excessively consumed by a function but I'm not able to identify the point at which this could be happening since it is a simple SELECT query and creation of an array with the values for be returned.

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 115540492288) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)

```
function funGetToken(){
        
        include_once(PATH_DATABASE_INC);
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $connection = $db->getConnection();         
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $arrayMain=[];
        $typeArray = [];
        $typeSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_tokentype";
        if ($result = $connection->query($typeSQL)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $typeArray[$row['id']] = $row['tokenType'];
            }
        }
        
        array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($typeArray));


        $sqlCmd="SELECT tb_tokens.symbol, tb_tokens.name, tb_tokens.idtype, tb_tokens.decimalCases, 
                        tb_tokens.maxSupply, tb_tokens.stake, tb_tokens.delegation, tb_tokens.description, tb_tokens.active, tb_gallery.path,
                        tb_tokens.idTbGallery
                 FROM tb_tokens
                 INNER JOIN tb_gallery
                 ON tb_tokens.idTbGallery = tb_gallery.id 
                 WHERE tb_tokens.id=".$id;

        $viArrayValues1 = [];
        
        if ($result = $connection->query($sqlCmd)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if(!empty($row)){
                while($row){
                    $viArrayValues['id']=$id;
                    $viArrayValues['symbol']=$row['symbol'];
                    $viArrayValues['name']=$row['name'];
                    $viArrayValues['idtype']=$row['idtype'];
                    $viArrayValues['decimalCases']=$row['decimalCases'];
                    $viArrayValues['maxSupply']=$row['maxSupply'];
                    $viArrayValues['stake']=$row['stake'];
                    $viArrayValues['delegation']=$row['delegation'];
                    $viArrayValues['active']=$row['active'];
                    $viArrayValues['description']=$row['description'];
                    $viArrayValues['path']=$row['path'];
                    $viArrayValues['idTbGallery']=$row['idTbGallery'];
                    array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($viArrayValues));
                }
            } else {
                $sqlCmd="SELECT tb_tokens.symbol, tb_tokens.name, tb_tokens.idtype, tb_tokens.decimalCases, 
                        tb_tokens.maxSupply, tb_tokens.stake, tb_tokens.delegation, tb_tokens.description, tb_tokens.active
                 FROM tb_tokens
                 WHERE tb_tokens.id=".$id;

                if ($result = $connection->query($sqlCmd)) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $viArrayValues['id']=$id;
                        $viArrayValues['symbol']=$row['symbol'];
                        $viArrayValues['name']=$row['name'];
                        $viArrayValues['idtype']=$row['idtype'];
                        $viArrayValues['decimalCases']=$row['decimalCases'];
                        $viArrayValues['maxSupply']=$row['maxSupply'];
                        $viArrayValues['stake']=$row['stake'];
                        $viArrayValues['delegation']=$row['delegation'];
                        $viArrayValues['active']=$row['active'];
                        $viArrayValues['description']=$row['description'];
                        $viArrayValues['path']="";
                        $viArrayValues['idTbGallery']="";
                        array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($viArrayValues));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($arrayMain);
        $db->closeConnection();
    }
```

I know I can increase the memory_limit but I still get the error or I get a timout error.
Other than that a simple SELECT and placing it in an array has no reason to need so much memory.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: How much is stored in the arrays before they are returned? Simply looks like you're trying to do something that the server is not capable of, as it does not have the right memory resources.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to generate what I would estimate to be a 20GB+ JSON document? Because that is going to be a huge problem to deal with no matter the circumstances.

Comment: It doesn't matter how simple the select is if it fetches more data than you have memory.

Comment: I would recommend to use Xdebug and step by step go through code. This give you possibility to understand where problem is.

Comment: ok I will try to use Xdebug.
The SELECT only returns one row
{
   "symbol":"BEE",
   "name":"Hive Engine Token",
   "idtype":"1",
   "decimalCases":"8",
   "maxSupply":"9007199254740991.00000000",
   "stake":"1",
   "delegation":"1",
   "description":"<p>dasdasd<\\/p>\\r\\n",
   "active":"0",
   "path":"assets\\/images\\/gallery\\/1.jpg",
   "idTbGallery":"1"
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem....

The $row it is an array like this [ "symbol":"BEE", "name":"Hive Engine Token", "idtype":"1", "decimalCases":"8", "maxSupply":"9007199254740991.00000000", "stake":"1", "delegation":"1", "description":"

dasdasd<\/p>\r\n", "active":"0", "path":"assets\/images\/gallery\/1.jpg", "idTbGallery":"1"]

So the while it is doing 11 times since each element it will be a element of $row.

Since in this case only one result can be retrieved since tb_tokens.id it is a primary key and cannot be duplicated the while can be removed and the code will be like that

```
function funGetToken(){         
        include_once(PATH_DATABASE_INC);
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $connection = $db->getConnection();         
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $arrayMain=[];
        $typeArray = [];
        $typeSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_tokentype";
        if ($result = $connection->query($typeSQL)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $typeArray[$row['id']] = $row['tokenType'];
            }
        }
        
        array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($typeArray));


        $sqlCmd="SELECT tb_tokens.symbol, tb_tokens.name, tb_tokens.idtype, tb_tokens.decimalCases,
                        tb_tokens.maxSupply, tb_tokens.stake, tb_tokens.delegation, tb_tokens.description,
                        tb_tokens.active, tb_gallery.path, tb_tokens.idTbGallery
                 FROM tb_tokens
                 INNER JOIN tb_gallery
                 ON tb_tokens.idTbGallery = tb_gallery.id 
                 WHERE tb_tokens.id=".$id;
                 
        $viArrayValues1 = [];
        
        if ($result = $connection->query($sqlCmd)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if(!empty($row)){
                    $viArrayValues['id']=$id;
                    $viArrayValues['symbol']=$row['symbol'];
                    $viArrayValues['name']=$row['name'];
                    $viArrayValues['idtype']=$row['idtype'];
                    $viArrayValues['decimalCases']=$row['decimalCases'];
                    $viArrayValues['maxSupply']=$row['maxSupply'];
                    $viArrayValues['stake']=$row['stake'];
                    $viArrayValues['delegation']=$row['delegation'];
                    $viArrayValues['active']=$row['active'];
                    $viArrayValues['description']=$row['description'];
                    $viArrayValues['path']=$row['path'];
                    $viArrayValues['idTbGallery']=$row['idTbGallery'];
                    array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($viArrayValues));
            } else {
                $sqlCmd="SELECT tb_tokens.symbol, tb_tokens.name, tb_tokens.idtype, tb_tokens.decimalCases, 
                        tb_tokens.maxSupply, tb_tokens.stake, tb_tokens.delegation, tb_tokens.description, tb_tokens.active
                 FROM tb_tokens
                 WHERE tb_tokens.id=".$id;

                if ($result = $connection->query($sqlCmd)) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $viArrayValues['id']=$id;
                        $viArrayValues['symbol']=$row['symbol'];
                        $viArrayValues['name']=$row['name'];
                        $viArrayValues['idtype']=$row['idtype'];
                        $viArrayValues['decimalCases']=$row['decimalCases'];
                        $viArrayValues['maxSupply']=$row['maxSupply'];
                        $viArrayValues['stake']=$row['stake'];
                        $viArrayValues['delegation']=$row['delegation'];
                        $viArrayValues['active']=$row['active'];
                        $viArrayValues['description']=$row['description'];
                        $viArrayValues['path']="";
                        $viArrayValues['idTbGallery']="";
                        array_push($arrayMain,json_encode($viArrayValues));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($arrayMain);
        $db->closeConnection();
    }
```